# Quitar caracteres a columnas de un archivo de texto

Tags: linux, bash

Tengo un archivo de texto que tiene como separador el carácter tubería (`|`).

Con instrucciones del intérprete quisiera mantener en la segunda columna solo dos caracteres y para la cuarta columna solo tres caracteres, ambos contados de izquierda a derecha.

Contenido de `archivo.txt` (inicio):

```
qwe|1203|asd|1.27|abc
qwe|53034|asd|5.274|abc
qwe|103|asd|1.2310|abc
```

Contenido esperado en `archivo.txt` (resultado final):

```
qwe|12|asd|1.2|abc
qwe|53|asd|5.2|abc
qwe|10|asd|1.2|abc
```

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: ¿Qué intentaste?

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, agrega lo que investigaste o trataste, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, no olvides realiza el [tour] del sitio, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar `printf` para ello:

```
# Generamos el archivo de prueba
echo "qwe|1203|asd|1.27|abc
qwe|53034|asd|5.274|abc
qwe|103|asd|1.2310|abc" > /tmp/pruebas

# Conversión
while IFS="|" read -r a b c d e
do
    printf "%s|%.2s|%s|%.3s|%s\n" $a $b $c $d $e
done < /tmp/pruebas

# En una línea:
while IFS="|" read -r a b c d e ; do printf "%s|%.2s|%s|%.3s|%s\n" $a $b $c $d $e ; done < /tmp/pruebas
```

Cambiando el valor de `IFS` podemos hacer que `read` trabaje con valores separados por caracteres `|` en vez de por espacios en blanco.

El punto `.` en los formatos `%.2s` y `%.3s` de `printf` está indicando que se muestren solo dos o tres caracteres y trunque el resto.

---

Otra forma alternativa es usar la expansión de parámetros [`${parametro:inicio:longitud}`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) de bash:

```
echo "$a|${b:0:2}|$c|${d:0:3}|$e"
```

Eso te permite, usando una posición negativa, recortar por la derecha en vez de la izquierda:

```
echo "$a|${b: -2:2}|$c|${d: -3:3}|$e"
```

Nota: es importante dejar el espacio en blanco antes del símbolo menos (`-`) para que el recorte funcione correctamente.

Comment: Muchas Graciasss!! , una ultima consulta , si con esto  %.2s  tengo los primeros 2 caracteres , como haría para tener los dos últimos caracteres

Comment: Acabo de editar mi respuesta con la forma de recortar por la derecha. Para ello he usado la funcionalidad de expansión de parámetros de bash.